# About Data Cleaning

Tags: python, sql, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I am a pretty amateur data science student and I am working on a project where I compared two servers in a team based game but my two datasets are formatted differently from one another. One column for instance would be first blood, where one set of data stores this information as "blue_team_first_blood" and is stored as True or False where as the other stores it as just "first blood" and stores integers, (1 for blue team, 2 for red team, 0 for no one if applicable)

I feel like I can code around these difference but whats the best practice? should I take the extra step to make sure both data sets are formatted correctly or does it matter at all?

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of time in the long run if you clean the data to make sure they're in the same format before you start your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Data cleaning is usually the first step in any data science project. It makes sense to transform the data into a consistent format before any further processing steps.

Answer (score 0):

you could consider transforming the "blue_team_first_blood" column to an integer format that is consistent with the other dataset, such as 1 for True and 0 for False. You could also consider renaming the "first blood" column in the second dataset to "blue_team_first_blood" to match the first dataset.

Overall, the best practice is to ensure that both datasets are formatted consistently and in a way that makes sense for your analysis. This will make it easier to compare the two datasets and draw meaningful insights.